# How to make `script` command loaded automatically on terminal login

Tags: linux, bash, debian, script, logging

`script` command allows to log gently everything that was put to console during session (like history but also displays results of commands). Everything is logged to file `typescript.xxx`

Now I want to run it in every terminal session that has been runned. I was trying to put `script` to `bashrc` but it falls into recursive loop (`script` is running it's own shell). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

add to

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

add

```
exec script
```

to the bottom (so it's the last thing loaded at login).

You will have to do this for every user though... but should get the job done.

Comment: This will only work if the user starts a login, non-interactive shell. Normally, opening a terminal runs an interactive shell so this will not work. Oh, and to do it for all users, just edit `/etc/profile`.

Answer (score 1):

[SnakeDoc's answer](https://superuser.com/a/565385/151431) might work if you can force all shells to be login shells. If you are connecting ti a remote server via ssh for example. If this is your local machine and you want `script` to be run every time you open a terminal, the only way I can think of is using the terminal's settings.

For example, using my personal favorite terminal ([terminator](http://software.jessies.org/terminator/), on debian installable with `sudo apt-get install terminator`), you can set a specific command to be run when opening a terminal. Open `~/.config/terminator/config` and add these lines to the  `[[default]]` profile:

```
use_custom_command = True
custom_command = script -a
```

You can also set it up so that `script` is only run for a specific profile. Add these lines after the `[[default]]` profile:

```
[[script]]
  use_custom_command = True
  custom_command = script -a
```

This creates a new profile called `script` which you can run by executing `terminator -p script`.

---

On `gnome-terminal`, you can do the same as follows:

[image]
[image]
[image]